# Why the bitrate shown during processing differs so much from the final bitrate after processing using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, bitrate, mkv

Using ffmpeg, why the bitrate shown during processing differs so much from the final bitrate after processing?

This command on a 1080p source:

```
ffmpeg -i "$name" -i "$subname" -map 0 -map 1 -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 21 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -c:s:0 srt -disposition:s:0 default -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:v:0 title="$title" "$new"
```

Shows this output:
[image]

Which essentially averages 1300-1400 kBit/s. But when I calculate the bitrate of the resulting video using `mkvinfo -t` the bitrate shown sits at ~970-1000 kBit/s and that's not even close to averaging the ~1300 kBit/s shown throughout processing. What is causing the disparity?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of mkvinfo:

> `mkvinfo -t`  Show statistics for each track in verbose mode.

I guess, you see the bitrate from the video track, while the ffmepg output is the average bitrate from the whole mkv (audio track + video track). The difference you notice is round about 300kBit/s which is near to your audio bitrate, which is 256kBit/s